# How to have Twilio say the current date in Studio

Tags: twilio

I'm not a programmer but I have been able to use Studio in Twilio to have it answer a call and play a file based on the date.  It is setting the variable as {{ 'now' | date: "%m-%d" }} and the playing the file {{flow.variables.Date}}.mp3

I would like to have it say "Reading for" DATE.  using my Date variable it only says the numbers (like 03 through 09).  How can I make it say the date like March 9th 2021?

Comment: Can you please show us / update your question with a screenshot of the Twilio Studio widget you're using? You want to use `Play` or `Say`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format `now` in a different way, like this:

```
{{ 'now' | date: "%B %d %Y" }}
```

Where:

- `%B`: The  full  month  name ("January")
- `%d`: Day of the month (01..31)
- `%Y`: Year with century

See [Twilio Liquid Template Language documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language#formatting-dates).

[image: Studio Flow Widget]

Comment: TY - I missed that page you linked to.  It worked perfectly!